# Asus PH GeForce gtx 1050ti Video Card and Intel UHD Graphics 630 Integrated Card

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, intel-graphics

I have searched everywhere but I was not able to find a specific answer to my problem. This is my first post, so please be gentle :) Thanks in advance.

The two video cards mentioned in the title are on my Desktop. I have two LG monitors, one is plugged with Asus 1050ti and the other LG monitor is plugged with Intel UHD 630, and both through their HDMI connections. Once I have installed Ubuntu 18.04, these two monitors were working in parallel (as extended monitor) with the above mentioned connection method. When I installed NVIDIA Driver, things started to get awkward. Now, I can only get one monitor working at a time, while switching between intel and nvidia Prime options.

However, on windows 10, which I installed along with Ubuntu 18.04, there are no issues and both monitor with the above-mentioned connection method are working like a charm.

So the question: How can I get the dual-monitors worked, while they are connected to different video card (mentioned in the title) outputs through HDMIs on both end?

I really need help! Thank you!

```
  -lshw -c video:
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GP107 [GeForce GTX 1050 Ti]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:127 memory:a3000000-a3ffffff memory:90000000-9fffffff memory:a0000000-a1ffffff ioport:4000(size=128) memory:a4000000-a407ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:124 memory:a2000000-a2ffffff memory:80000000-8fffffff ioport:5000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

Answer (score 1):

So here is my solution.

Uninstall any manually installed NVIDIA drivers.

Then reboot and reinstall using Software & Updates. But here, there is a very important thing to do.

ONLY CHOOSE and old version of NVIDIA DRIVER. In my case, **nvidia-driver-390** did the trick.

Thank you anyways. My first question it was and not it is the first response from myself. But this could really help to many others.